# Using vue-meeting-selector template but not able to display the calendar

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to create a calendar with slots for appointments so the user can click and pick a time to make a booking.
I am using the template from the package vue-meeting-selector. The problem is that the calendar itself doesnt display on the page.

This is the code for the template

`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-meeting-selector
      class="simple-example__meeting-selector"
      v-model="meeting"
      :date="date"
      :loading="loading"
      :class-names="classNames"
      :meetings-days="meetingsDays"
      @next-date="nextDate"
      @previous-date="previousDate"
    />
    <p>meeting Selected: {{ meeting ? meeting : "No Meeting selected" }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueMeetingSelector from "vue-meeting-selector";
import data from "./data.json";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueMeetingSelector,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
      meetingsDays: [],
      meeting: { date: "2021-01-15T08:00:00.000Z" },
      loading: true,
      nbDaysToDisplay: 5,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // @click on button-right
    async nextDate() {
      console.log("nextDate");
    },
    // @click on button-left
    async previousDate() {
      console.log("previousDate");
    },
  },
  async created() {
    this.meetingsDays = data;
    this.loading = false;
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

`

I did import the package on my component
`import VueMeetingSelector from "vue-meeting-selector";`

and I also installed the package npm install --save vue-meeting-selector

I get no error when trying to run the frontend. It just doesnt display the calendar.
Any idea what I could be missing

Sources where I got this template from:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-meeting-selector-ex-forked-lyw515?file=/src/App.vue:0-1084
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-meeting-selector?activeTab=readme

Comment: 0



I found the problem of why it wasn't working. The new version of the package 2.0.0-beta-3 didn't work on my project. After some digging, I found an older version of this package. Changed on the package.json and package-lock.json, did a npm install and got the correct packages. The calendar displays great now!

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use `slotsGeneratorAsync` and import styles `import 'vue-meeting-selector/dist/style.css';`.

[check out this example](https://vue-meeting-selector.tuturu.io/#simpleexample)